# Passing Azure DevOps pipeline secrets in tasks

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to pass the Azure DevOps pipeline secrets without passing them as task env variables

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables), we can only pass the secrets like below

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "recommended: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```

This works okay when you have 1 or 2 variables, but managing 20 or more than that becomes so tedious.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @VINOD KUMAR.  I understand your question again and updated answer. Please check below. Feel free to let me know if it could give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

> Is there a way to pass the Azure DevOps pipeline secrets without passing them as task env variables

I'm afraid there is no method to use secret variables directly without mapping them to the task environment.

From [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) you mentioned：

> Don't set secret variables in your YAML file. Operating systems often
> log commands for the processes that they run, and you wouldn't want
> the log to include a secret that you passed in as an input. Use the
> script's environment or map the variable within the variables block to
> pass secrets to your pipeline.

We don't recommend passing the secret variables directly into pipeline. So we could use the env variable to map the secret variable.

Generally, we only place a small number of secret variables  in a single task.

Therefore, it is valuable to use environment variables to map secret variables.

Comment: I understand but just wanted to see If there are any other options. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @VINODKUMAR. Thanks for your feedback. If you want to use other methods, [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1) is another option. But there should be no convenient way to pass multiple secret variables at once.

Comment: On the other hand, if the answer could  give you some help, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.